# Node that generates key or mouse events at low level?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to generate keyboard and mouse presses at the X11 level, so applications or even other ros nodes that are reading the keyboard directly can be tested or remotely controlled.

http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html

I'll make one if it doesn't already exist.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228956/node-that-generates-key-or-mouse-events-at-low-level?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-03-13**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/44709/how-can-i-automate-my-ros-work-session-environment/

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-03-13**:
libxdo-dev and xdotool

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-03-13**:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/robhum_ui_utils/tree/master/virtual_keyboard - but is using subprocess rather than libxdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/lucasw/xdo_ros - currently takes String inputs for key down, up, or key strings, and mouse absolute position and relative moves using opencv_apps/Point2D messages.  Needs a window selection service, it only uses the current window now.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0